# jQuery addClass() not working given an ID

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/search",
  data: $("form").serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
    $("#tab").addClass("loading"); // THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK
    // . . . LOAD SEARCH RESULTS HERE (USUALLY TAKES SEVERAL SECONDS) . . .
    $("#tab").removeClass("loading");
  }
});
```

And I have the following CSS:

```
.loading {
  background: transparent url(../resources/images/loading.gif) no-repeat right center;
  text-indent: -1000px;
}
```

And I have the following relevant HTML:

```
<div id="tab">
  <table id="searchResultsGrid"></table>
</div>
```

I can't get the line `$("#tab").addClass("loading")` to work. Watching in FireBug, the class `.loading` is never added to the `#tab` object.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: what does the html look like? why are you adding the loading class AFTER the success of the ajax call? you should add it right before the ajax call, then remove it in the success function

Comment: maybe its beacuse u add and remove at the same time ?

Comment: How do you know that it is not working? Is the success function getting called back?
Add an alert inside success block to see if you get alert. Can you show the html for tab element?

Comment: The actually loading of the search results takes several seconds, and that's what I want to show the progress for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead. What's probably happening is that it's adding and removing the `loading` class quickly enough that it steps on itself

```
// add the class before the ajax call
$("#tab").addClass("loading");

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/search",
  data: $("form").serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
    // . . . LOAD SEARCH RESULTS HERE . . .
  }
  complete: function(data) {
    // remove the class on complete, not success, in case of an error
    $("#tab").removeClass("loading");
  }
});
```

Comment: You can also use beforeSend to add the class before ajax starts

Comment: Adding the "complete" callback function and moving "addClass()" outside of the "success" callback did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the HTML, it's hard to say, but one thing that stands out is that you're adding the class once the ajax call returns with a success. Try changing to this:

```
$("#tab").addClass("loading");

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/search",
  data: $("form").serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
    // . . . LOAD SEARCH RESULTS HERE . . .
    $("#tab").removeClass("loading");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the class prior to the ajax call and then remove it in the success function.  What you are doing is setting it and then removing it in the same code execution.  The class will not visually update until the code completes execution, at which point you have already removed the class.

Answer (score 0):

first you addClass loading ,then you removeClass loading ,that's why you didn't see it working , you should add loading class before the ajax call, when the call returns success, you can removeClass